# Apache Airflow for user-driven Business Processes

Tags: airflow, business-process-management

I've read parts of the airflow documentation and seen some videos. I'm curious if airflow would make sense in a more user driven process.

Let's say, you have a webpage:

- customers can select products, put them in a shopping-basket and finally order and pay them.
- your co-worker will later process those orders, collect them in the warehouse and ship them.

Would airflow fit in that case?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend AirFlow for such scenarios. It has severe scalability limitations and very limiting workflow specification language. Look at cadenceworkflow.io which was created for application level workflows like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I've only begun to investigate AirFlow for complex workflows.  I think the situation you are describing can be completed with standard web-application services.  However, I do believe there are user-driven business cases.  An example might be data-analyst looking to pull some report that requires data/aggregate-calcs from disparate data-sources.

Comment: Well, I want to  **create** a web-service using airflow. I know traditionally you would do this by saving the state to a database and go from there. The question is if I do this using airflow instead. I've found Spiffworkflow which seems to support user-centered workflow. The thing with Spiffworkflow is, that it seemes unused (and maybe unsupported) for some time.

Comment: looked at spiffworkflow, have a better idea of what you are asking.  I think if you wanted to use airflow in this manner you would need to have it work-in-coordination with another service that acts as the event-bus/orchestration-engine.  Especially if you are looking to support the workflow patterns that spiffworkflow is adopting.

Comment: I guess my first problem is that the abbrevation bpm and the term behind is loaded with all kinds of similar and not-so-similar stuff.
Googleing the stuff is easy, finding what they really do. Or what the really mean to do is often hidden behind buzzword-bingo documentation :-/